# how to close form after it focedout

Tags: jquery, forms

I have form and created `focusout` event but when I try to fill in this form it `slidesUp`. When I put `blur` event for form's fields it disappears after the first iput element

```
$('.login').focusout( function(){
$('.login form').slideUp(300);})
```

Comment: Add your code to solving problem.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: because login form gets focusout.

Comment: alternatively you can add a close button to the form.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6vrd1nkn/